AWS Deployment OF React Application
So i was deploying my project to AWS Amplify and there was a part of the code that im having error so my github repo looks like  this

so the repo has a folder inside, inside that is my project so the problem is how can i direct the path to tianmeds-portfolio in my AWS this is the error code im experiencing

my package.json is inside the tianmeds-portfolio folder how can i direct it when im deploying
